# Login Firebase utilizando o GoogleSign

Tags: android, firebase, google-api

Estou tentando realiza o login na aplicação no Firebase através do GoogleSign desta forma:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;

/**
 * A login screen that offers login via email/password.
 */
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{


    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    private final int RC_SIGN_IN = 21212;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        SignInButton mSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        mSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
        mSignIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                attemptLogin();
            }
        });

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail().requestIdToken(getString(R.string.api_key))
                .build();


        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext()).enableAutoManage(this, this).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API).build();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if(opr.isDone()){
            Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }else{

            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            final GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            final String token = acct.getIdToken();
            final String name = acct.getDisplayName();
            final String serverAuth = acct.getServerAuthCode();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.no_login, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    private void attemptLogin() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);


    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

O meu problema é que sempre retorna `null` no método `handleSignInResult`!

Criei este projeto pelo Firebase, adicionei o arquivo google-services.json na pasta `app` e adicionei a permissão de `Internet` !

Minha dúvida é se preciso liberar algo no [console.developer.google.com](http://console.developer.google.com) ou quando habilito esta opção no [console.firebase.google.com](https://console.firebase.google.com/) já fvaz todo este processo?

Comment: +1, também estou com dificuldades no Login com Firebase...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui solucionar da seguinte forma:

Além de atualizar o arquivo `google-services.json` utilizei a chave de Web
 Client no gerado no [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com/)

Este é requisitado na seguinte parte:

```
 GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).

    requestProfile()

    .requestEmail()
    /*  INFORMAR WEB CLIENT DO OAuth 2.0 */
    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.api_key))

    .build();
```